# Display entries by category (multiple categories)

Tags: entries, categories, filter, category

I would like to know how I can create a page that contains all entries from a section e.g. 'news'. I want to divide the entries by their given category.

News (section)

Category 1:

- entry in category 1
- second entry in category 1
- third entry in category 1

Category 2:

- entry in category 2
- second entry in category 2
- third entry in category 2

etc.

Does anyone know the code for this? The categories are all in the same category group.

Answer (score 6):

You can use .relatedTo(category)

```
{% for category in craft.categories.group('categoryName') %}
  <h2>{{category.title}}</h2>
  {% for entry in craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category) %}
    <a href="{{entry.url}}">{{entry.title}}</a><br>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

You can check for length if you don't want to show categories which aren't related to any entry.

[See the relations documentation](https://craftcms.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param//)