# How to display entries by descendants of a particular category slug

Tags: entries, categories

I'm trying to display entries (with a category heading) by only the descendants of a particular category slug.

So it would be similar to this:

[Display entries by category (multiple categories)](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/14508/display-entries-by-category-multiple-categories)

but instead of showing an entire category group it would just be the children of a particular slug.

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on this?  Thanks!